# How to hide PTCardTabBar?

Tags: ios, swift

I use `PTCardTabBarController` like custom tab bar. I want to hide tab bar in my `ViewController`. I trying to use in storyboard `Hide Bottom Bar on Push` or in code: `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true`. But it not helped me.

When I stat to use `PTCardTabBar` I have next scheme in storyboard:

**TabBarController** (with class `PTCardTabBarController` and module `PTCardTabBar`) **->** **NavigationBarController** **->** **ViewController**.

Next I launch my app and I see under my `PTCardTabBar` system iOS tab bar. I use in storyboard `Hide Bottom Bar on Push` but it is hide only system tab bar and not `PTCardTabBar`. How to fix it and hide both tab bars?

Comment: As a general rule, hiding the tab bar is not recommended as it can lead to confusing navigation for the user. Is your design really a tab bar, where one of the tabs contains a navigation controller, and when you push to a new controller in that nav controller you want to hide the tab bar?

Comment: @DonMag my storyboard design: https://ibb.co/n7qrxTq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a quick look at that `PTCardTabBar` library...

What you see on-screen is not a `UITabBar` ... it is a `UIView`. So, any normal actions on a standard Tab Bar Controller's TabBar will not be related.

To hide it, you need to edit `PTCardTabBarController.swift` and make its `customTabBar` available to your code:

```
// make this "open"
open lazy var customTabBar: PTCardTabBar = {
    return PTCardTabBar()
}()
```

Then, when you want to hide the tab bar (for example, in `viewDidLoad()` in your view controller:

```
if let ptcTBC = tabBarController as? PTCardTabBarController {
    ptcTBC.customTabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

You'll also (obviously) need to set `.isHidden` back to false to show it again.

Probably, though, you want to do more than just have it showing or hidden... in which case you could further modify `PTCardTabBarController.swift` to add a function to animate it into or out-of view (for example).

Comment: This hides my tab bar view (UIView) . But there is an empty space identical in size with tab bar between the content and the bottom edge of the screen if I use `safe area` constraints. Of course I can use constraint to superview but it is not very good. How to fix it?

Comment: @User - that sounds like a different question. If this answered *this* question, mark it as accepted and post a new question with the new issue. (if you do, I'd suggest including screen-caps, as the description in this comment does not make it clear).

Comment: please check my new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983414/how-to-remove-empty-space-behind-the-ptcardtabbar-when-it-is-hidden