# How to remove empty space behind the `PTCardTabBar` when it is hidden?

Tags: ios, swift

I use `PTCardTabBar` like a custom tab bar. I need to hide my tab bar in some controllers. I use this code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63980566) to do it:

in `PTCardTabBarController` class: add `public`

```
public lazy var customTabBar: PTCardTabBar = {
    return PTCardTabBar()
}()
```

and in my `ViewController`:

```
if let ptcTBC = tabBarController as? PTCardTabBarController {
    ptcTBC.customTabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

My tab bar is hidden, but I have empty space in its place.

for example:

I have constraint to safe area between my label and screen edge. And if I not use `PTCardTabBar` I get right result:

[image]

But if I use `PTCardTabBar` and hide it I get this bad result:

[image]

It is seems like tab bar is hidden but empty space not disappear. How to fix it?

**UPDATE**

Based on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983414/how-to-remove-empty-space-behind-the-ptcardtabbar-when-it-is-hidden#comment113143053_63983414) I check `PTCardTabBarController` and in `viewDidLoad` I find this line:

```
self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: tabBarHeight + bottomSpacing, right: 0)
```

If I change it on:

```
self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

My problem is solved and everything display correctly. But what's the best way to change this line to `bottom: 0` when I go to view controller where my tab bar is hidden and change it to `tabBarHeight + bottomSpacing` when I return to previous controller where my tab bar is not hidden?

Comment: From the linked answer, I think this is the key text "What you see on-screen is not a UITabBar ... it is a UIView. So, any normal actions on a standard Tab Bar Controller's TabBar will not be related."  > so you are 'hiding' a UIView - but hiding a view isn't the same thing as making it go away, it just isn't visible.   I'm not familiar with this custom tab bar specifically - but that's where I'd start - by looking to see if I can remove instead of hide!

Comment: You'll need to do some digging into that `PTCardTabBarController` code. For one thing, it is modifying the `.additionalSafeAreaInsets` of the tab bar controller. Important to note that the tab bar ***is still there*** and affecting the safe area... it's just hidden. Removing / hiding the tab bar is an odd design anyway - users are accustomed to seeing a tab bar, not having it disappear / reappear. Depending on what you're planning on doing from this point, you may want to *present* the controller as full-screen modal instead of pushing it.

Comment: @DonMag I understand that this way to using tab bar(removing / hiding) is not the best. However, in the current design of my application, I need to do this. If I change in .additionalSafeAreaInsets `bottom: tabBarHeight + bottomSpacing` to `bottom: 0` it will help. But what the right way to change it to `0` if I go to `ViewController` and `PTCardTabBar` is hidden and change it to `bottom: tabBarHeight + bottomSpacing` if return to previous controller where `PTCardTabBar` is not hidden?

Comment: @DonMag please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63994999/14207208 Is this not bad solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you'll need to do some digging into that `PTCardTabBarController` code.

I spent a few minutes playing with it, and this might help you out... tried to make as few changes as possible, so I only edited `PTCardTabBarController.swift`.

So...

- added Two constraint vars: customTabBar Bottom Anchor and customTabBar Top Anchor
- the bottom anchor constrains the Bottom of the custom tab bar to the top of the "small view". This will be active when the tab bar is showing.
- the top anchor constrains the Top of the custom tab bar to the Bottom of the view. This will be active when the tab bar is hidden.
- added a `showTabBar()` func to show/hide the custom tab bar with optional animation.
- in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` set the frame of the hidden "built-in" tab bar to below the bottom of the view.

Now I can, for example, do this:

```
if let ptcTBC = tabBarController as? PTCardTabBarController {
    ptcTBC.showTabBar(false, animated: true)
}
performSegue(withIdentifier: mySegueID, sender: indexPath)
```

and then on return:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let ptcTBC = tabBarController as? PTCardTabBarController {
        ptcTBC.showTabBar(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I forked that `PTCardTabBar` repo and added a complete example here: https://github.com/DonMag/PTCardTabBar-1

Answer (score 0):

Based on @DonMag [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983414/how-to-remove-empty-space-behind-the-ptcardtabbar-when-it-is-hidden#comment113143053_63983414) I do this:

In `PTCardTabBarController` in `viewDidLoad` **remove** this line:

```
self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: tabBarHeight + bottomSpacing, right: 0)
```

to show tab bar:

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    
if let ptcTBC = tabBarController as? PTCardTabBarController {
    ptcTBC.customTabBar.isHidden = false
    ptcTBC.customTabBar.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - bottomPadding! - 90
}
```

to hide tab bar :

```
if let ptcTBC = tabBarController as? PTCardTabBarController {
    ptcTBC.customTabBar.isHidden = true
}
```